# 'StaticResourceExtension' is not valid for Setter.Value. - new error after installing VS2022

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2022, wpf-style

I have a little WPF I am creating (Self taught).
It was created in VS2021 I believe however my PC died (Motherboard).
I have reinstalled everything on a new PC and brought over the backups and have since installed VS2022.

Upon opening I am getting heaps of errors (30) on my app.xml style section.
This was working fine and weirdly still will run and compile but obviously I'm not doing something right.

Interstingly some sections are working and others aren't.
The main ones not working are referencing the SOLIDCOLORBRUSH at the top which is setting my colours for the app.

the main errors are:

> Error XDG0062 'StaticResourceExtension' is not valid for Setter.Value.
> The only supported MarkupExtension types are DynamicResourceExtension
> and BindingBase or derived types.
>
> Error XDG0062 The resource "brdrTeal" has an incompatible type.
>
> Error XDG0062 'txtTitle' resource not found.

These are all referenced with {StaticResource XXXXX}

Finally this section has this error:

Error:

> Error XDG0062 '{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}' is not a valid value
> for the 'System.Windows.Controls.Control.Template' property on a
> Setter.

Code:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                        <Border x:Name="Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="{StaticResource Teal2}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="#00827b"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>



<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                        <Border x:Name="Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="{StaticResource Teal2}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="#00827b"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

I've included a chunk of the app.xaml file below, to see how I have laid everything out.
Keen to do this properly if this is an incorrect way to do this, as I meantioned I'm just learning this now.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Teal1" Color="#67DAD5" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Teal2" Color="#39c0c0" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Teal3" Color="#00bab3" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Teal4" Color="#00a09b" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Teal5" Color="#00827b" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="mintGreen" Color="#a4e9c6" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Teal2Light" Color="#c9e9ea" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightGrey" Color="#f6f6f6" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MidGrey" Color="#aaaaad" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DarkGrey" Color="#56565b" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Burgundy1" Color="#8C0F57" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Burgundy2" Color="#deb9c7" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="activeAreaColour" Color="#c9e9ea"/>

           
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            <Setter Property="ShowInTaskbar" Value="false"/>
        </Style>



        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}" x:Key="toolTipImage">
            <Setter Property="RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode" Value="Fant" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10 10 0 0"/>
        </Style>



        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" >
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Teal2}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="white" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource Teal5}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1 1 1 1"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1,-1,0,0" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="28" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="auto"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>


        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right" />

            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Teal2Light}" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource Teal5}" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="black" />
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
                </Trigger>

            </Style.Triggers>

        </Style>


        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border
                  x:Name="Border" 
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                  CornerRadius="2"
                  Background="{DynamicResource Teal5}"
                  BorderBrush="{DynamicResource Teal5}"
                  BorderThickness="2" />
                <Border x:Name="lrgBorder"
  Grid.Column="0"
  CornerRadius="2,0,0,2" 
  Margin="1" 
  Background="{DynamicResource Teal2Light}" 
  BorderBrush="{DynamicResource Teal2Light}"
  BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" />
                <Path 
      x:Name="Arrow"
      Grid.Column="1"     
      Fill="White"
      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
      VerticalAlignment="Center"
      Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Burgundy1}" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Teal5}" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Burgundy2}" />
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Burgundy1}" />
                    <Setter TargetName="lrgBorder" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LightGrey}" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Burgundy1}"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource Burgundy2}" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
        </ControlTemplate>

        <Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}" TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120"/>
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Grid>
                            <ToggleButton 
                                Name="ToggleButton" 
                                Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" 
                                Grid.Column="2" 
                                Focusable="false"
                                IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                ClickMode="Press">
                            </ToggleButton>
                            <ContentPresenter
                                Name="ContentSite"
                                IsHitTestVisible="False" 
                                Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                                ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                                Margin="3,3,23,3"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                            <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                                Style="{x:Null}" 
                                Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                Margin="3,3,23,3"
                                Focusable="True" 
                                Background="Transparent"
                                Visibility="Hidden"
                                IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                            <Popup 
                                Name="Popup"
                                Placement="Bottom"
                                IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                                AllowsTransparency="True" 
                                Focusable="False"
                                PopupAnimation="Slide">
                                <Grid 
                                  Name="DropDown"
                                  SnapsToDevicePixels="True"                
                                  MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                                  MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                    <Border 
                                        x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                        Background="{StaticResource Teal2Light}"
                                        BorderThickness="1"
                                        BorderBrush="{StaticResource Teal5}"/>
                                    <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Grid>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                                <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Burgundy1}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="4"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEditable"
           Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility"    Value="Visible"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>


        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                        <Border x:Name="Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="{StaticResource Teal2}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="#00827b"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#c9e9ea" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#67DAD5" Offset="1.0"/>
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>




        <Style x:Key="activeBackground" TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Teal2}"/>
        </Style>

        <sys:Double x:Key="fntButton">18</sys:Double>
        <sys:Double x:Key="fntButtonSmall">12</sys:Double>

        <sys:Double x:Key="ftnTextBox">15</sys:Double>

        <Style x:Key="brdrTeal" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Teal2}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        </Style>


        <Style x:Key="activeArea" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource activeAreaColour}"/>
        </Style>


        <Style x:Key="brdrBurgundy" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Burgundy1}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        </Style>

        <Style  TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 10 0 0"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="DemiBold"/>
        </Style>

        <!--#region TxtBoxes and passwordbox-->

        <Style x:Key="txtWhite" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource ftnTextBox}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource brdrTeal}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="txtGrey" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource ftnTextBox}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LightGrey}"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5 0 0 0"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 10 0 0"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MidGrey}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="border" Value="2"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Teal2}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="border" Value="2"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Teal2}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Teal2Light}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Burgundy1}"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="DemiBold"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>

        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="txtPassGrey" TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource ftnTextBox}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LightGrey}"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
                        <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Teal2}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="border" Value="2"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Teal2}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Teal2Light}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Burgundy1}"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="DemiBold"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <!--#endregion -->


        


    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: "Error XDG0062 The resource "brdrTeal" has an incompatible type" - brdrTeal is a `Style`. you are using it for BorderBrush property which is a Brush: `<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource brdrTeal}"/>`. error text clearly says that

Comment: Thanks Ash, Yes I misread that one, its just weird that it has worked for a year but now is showing as an error with new VS?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic values need DynamicResource.
Change e.g

```
Background="{StaticResource Teal5}"
```

to

```
Background="{DynamicResource Teal5}"
```